# How can i call recyclerview adapter in another class?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I wanna update my `RecyclerView` list in another class. I can't call `RecyclerView` adapter in the second class, actually when the adapter is initialized there, an error is shown "classXXX is not an enclosing class". How can I do that?

Here is my `Fragment` which contains `RecyclerView` named `AllworksFragment`:

```
package ir.applinkfinder.hw6;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;
import ir.applinkfinder.hw6.model.WorksModel;
import ir.applinkfinder.hw6.model.WorksRepository;

/**
* A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class AllworksFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private MyAdapter myAdapter;
private Button mButtonInsert;
private Button mButtonRemove;
private EditText mEditTextInsert;
private EditText mEditTextRemove;
private FloatingActionButton mFloatingActionButtonAdd;
private Button mButtonAdd;

public AllworksFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_allworks, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    mFloatingActionButtonAdd = view.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton_add);
    mButtonAdd = view.findViewById(R.id.button_test_addd);

    mButtonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = AddItemToListActivity.newIntent(getActivity());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    mFloatingActionButtonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
//                Intent intent = AddItemToListActivity.;
                Intent intent = AddItemToListActivity.newIntent(getActivity());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    myRecyclerViewLayoutManager();
    updateUI();

    return view;
}

private void myRecyclerViewLayoutManager(){
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity())); // moshakhas mikone recyclerview chejuri namayesh dade beshe
//        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));

   //        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
//        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL) ;
 //        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
}//myRecyclerViewLayoutManager();

private void updateUI(){
    WorksRepository worksRepository = WorksRepository.getInstance();
    List<WorksModel> works = worksRepository.getmWorksList();
    if (myAdapter == null) {
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(works);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
    else{
//            workAdapter.setCrimeList(works);
//            myAdapter.setWorkList(works);

    /*
    notifyDataSetChanged() method should be called after
    you've updated the list which holds all your data,
    in order to refresh the RecyclerView
    */

        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // jahate update e list bad az taqyir e edit text ha, in kole list racheck mikonad

     //            myAdapter.notifyItemChanged(positionnnn); // notifyItemChanged faqat haman position e khas ra check mikonad
    }
}//updateUI


//ViewHolder
public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    protected TextView mTextViewTitle;
    protected TextView mTextViewDetail;
    protected TextView mTextViewDate;
    protected TextView mTextViewHour;

    public myViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextViewTitle  =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_title);
        mTextViewDetail =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_detail);
        mTextViewDate   =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_date);
        mTextViewHour   =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_hour);


    }
}//ViewHolder

 //    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 //    CustomListListener mListener;
 //    public interface CustomListListener{
 //        void onListChanged(List<WorksModel> myList);
 //    }
 //    public void setOnListChangeListener(CustomListListener listener){
 //        this.mListener = listener;
 //    }



    // Adapter
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myViewHolder>{

    private List<WorksModel> worksList;

    public MyAdapter(List<WorksModel> workM) {
        worksList = workM;
    }

    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item_list, parent, false);
        return new myViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        WorksModel worksModel = worksList.get(position);
        holder.mTextViewTitle.setText(worksModel.getTitle());
        holder.mTextViewDetail.setText(worksModel.getDetail());
 //            holder.mTextViewDate.setText(worksModel.getDate());
        holder.mTextViewHour.setText(worksModel.getHour());



        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = WorkDetailActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), worksList.get(position).getTitle());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

  }

//        private void myAddItemMethod(int position, WorksRepository worksRepository){

   //        }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return worksList.size();
       }
    }//Adapter

 }
```

And this is the `Fragment` which i wish to add some new data to `RecyclerView`:

```
 package ir.applinkfinder.hw6;
import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.ImageButton;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Date;

 import ir.applinkfinder.hw6.model.WorksModel;
 import ir.applinkfinder.hw6.model.WorksRepository;

 public class AddItemToListFragment extends Fragment{ // implements WorksRepository.CustomListListener {

    WorksRepository mWorksRepository;

     private ArrayList<WorksModel> mWorksList;

     private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;


     private EditText mEditTextAddTitle;
     private EditText mEditTextAddDetail;
     private EditText mEditTextAddDate;
     private EditText mEditTextAddHour;
     private ImageButton mImageButtonAddDone;

public AddItemToListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_item_to_list, container, false);

 //        WorksRepository.setOnListChangeListener(this);

    mEditTextAddTitle   = view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_add_title);
    mEditTextAddDetail  = view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_add_details);
    mEditTextAddDate    = view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_add_date);
    mEditTextAddHour    = view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_add_hour);
    mImageButtonAddDone = view.findViewById(R.id.imagebutton_add_done);

    mImageButtonAddDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            insertItem();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public void insertItem(){
    mAdapter = new AllworksFragment.MyAdapter(mWorksRepository.getmWorksList());
 //        mAdapter = new AllworksFragment.MyAdapter(mWorksRepository);

    mWorksRepository = new WorksRepository();
    WorksModel worksModel = new WorksModel();
    worksModel.setTitle(mEditTextAddTitle.getText().toString());
    worksModel.setDetail(mEditTextAddDetail.getText().toString());
 //        worksModel.setDate(Date);
    worksModel.setDate(new Date());
    worksModel.setHour(mEditTextAddHour.getText().toString());

    mWorksRepository.getmWorksList().add(worksModel);
 //        mWorksList.add(worksModel);

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}//insertItem
}
```

The problem is that in `insertItem()` method, I can't initialize `RecyclerView` adapter. It invokes error:
"`AllworksFragment` is not an enclosing fragment"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is not an enclosing class Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252727/is-not-an-enclosing-class-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView - Access to a list from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52347367/recyclerview-access-to-a-list-from-another-class)